# Difference between XMPP and RSS from real-time perspective

Tags: rss, xmpp, real-time

I have a general question here regarding the RSS and XMPP technology. I want to know what exactly makes XMPP a real-time alternative to RSS?

Right now, I'm assuming a one-way message stream (from server to client ONLY).

What I'm confused about is, let's say I program a RSS reader on my client side and make it scan for new feeds for VERY short interval of time. Will that not make my system real-time'ish? Or is there any negative impact on doing that which XMPP resolves (apart from the security features)?

Because there are some systems which uses a combination of the two to form a real-time feeding system (Eg : [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com)).

So, if someone can briefly explain why someone would implement XMPP over RSS when designing a real-time notification system, I'd highly appreciate that.

Sorry for the long post, I have recently begun with these two technologies and I'm very curious about their functionalities.  I tried looking up on the internet but the answers were either too brief or insufficient.

Answer (score 3):

These are very different things, but complementary.

RSS is *just* a data format. It does not involve any "latency" by itself. It's just the way it's being consumed which determines if it can be realtime or not.

XMPP is a communication protocol. It's connected and in that regard can be considered as "real-time". RSS itself (or rather Atom), as it's XML, can be transported quite easily over XMPP. That's one of the ways you can make RSS realtime.

Answer (score 1):

And RSS can be realtime if it's served through the PubSubHubbub protocol (is not it, Julien :-) !